# Can't create database 'opensips'; database exists

Tags: database, opensips

When trying to create a database for OpenSIPS I got this error:

```
root@root:/etc/opensips# opensipsdbctl create
MySQL password for root:
INFO: test server charset
INFO: creating database opensips ...
ERROR 1007 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create database 'opensips'; database exists
ERROR: Creating database opensips failed!
```

Comment: Well it already exists ...  what do you want to know beyond that?

Comment: Please confirm if you are using Debian or Ubuntu (as you're an Ask Ubuntu user and your terminal looks like a Debian-based distro's terminal).

Comment: yes i'm using debian

Answer (score 1):

You may have executed this command before, although it was not successful, but the database was built.
Directly drop the opensips database and re-execute the command.

```
root@root:/etc/opensips# mysql -u root -p
MySQL password for root:
mysql> DROP DATABASE opensips;
mysql> quit
root@root:/etc/opensips# opensipsdbctl create
```